# stored procedure to send e-mail used to work, but not working altough it does not returns any error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

so, i got this stored procedure. i use sql server 2016. this procedure does the following, it checks certain files validity (based upon time, we set a date for some files to end). when that validity is reached, this procedure should send an e-mail for two addresses, in order for us to know what file has reached its end.
if i run the select, isolated, it works like a charm. the whole code does not return errors but it does not send e-mails. any thoughts on what could be wrong?

```
USE [MASS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[DossierEmailSend]    Script Date: 06/11/2019 10:00:44 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DossierEmailSend]
AS
 --Create a holding table for the dossiers that met the criteria

DECLARE @dossiers TABLE (col1 varchar(100), col2 varchar(100), col3 varchar(100), col4 varchar(100));

 --Insert the dossiers that met the criteria

INSERT INTO @dossiers
SELECT no, nome, obrano, convert(varchar,datafinal) col4  
    FROM bo
    WHERE nmdos LIKE '%preço%'
    AND datafinal = DATEADD(day, -1, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))

 --Create a row check to determine whether to send the email or not

DECLARE @rows int;
SET @rows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @dossiers)

 --Set the body elements

DECLARE @message varchar(1000);
-- declare the xml data to pass to the HTML body
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX);
-- body will hold the HTML formatted table in the email
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX);

 --Create the columns that will hold each row of data as xml

SET @xml = CAST(( SELECT col1 AS 'td','',col2 AS 'td','', col3 AS 'td','', col4 AS 'td'
FROM @dossiers
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

 --Set the HTML for the body

SET @body ='<html><body><H3>Dossier Info</H3>
<table border = 1> 
<tr>
<th> Num </th> <th> Nome </th> <th> Dossier </th> <th> Data de Fecho </th></tr>'

 --Stitch everything together, appending the HTML table

SET @body = @body + @xml +'</table></body></html>'

SET NOCOUNT ON 

 --Check if any dossiers met the criteria

IF @rows > 0 
BEGIN

 --Send the email and append the data table to the body

EXEC dbo.uspSendEmail 'Encerramento Dossier Preços', 'email2@domain.pt', @body, NULL, 'email1@domain.pt'
SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

the DDL code is the following:

```
USE [MASS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[uspSendEmail]    Script Date: 06/11/2019 11:49:50 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[uspSendEmail]
 @subject nvarchar(max),
 @to nvarchar(max),
 @body nvarchar(max),
 @file nvarchar(max)='',
 @cc nvarchar(max)='',
 @bcc nvarchar(max)='',
 @query nvarchar(max)='',
 @attach_query_result_as_file tinyint=0,
 @query_attachment_filename nvarchar(max)=''
 as      

 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = NULL,
 @body_format = 'HTML',
 @copy_recipients = @cc,
 @blind_copy_recipients = @bcc,
 @recipients = @to,
 @body = @body,
 @subject = @subject,
 @file_attachments = @file,
 @query = @query, 
 @attach_query_result_as_file = @attach_query_result_as_file,
 @query_attachment_filename = @query_attachment_filename 
 return 0
```

got a new code, like this:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @profile_name = 'SQL-PHC',  
    @recipients = 'email@domain.pt',  
    @query = 'SELECT no, nome, obrano,   
    convert(varchar,datafinal)  
    FROM bo
    WHERE nmdos LIKE "Preços por Cliente"
    AND datafinal = DATEADD(day, -1, CONVERT(date, 
    GETDATE()))' ,  
    @subject = 'Work Order Count',  
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;
```

Comment: Odd that you're using a User defined Stored procedure here, and not `sp_send_dbmail`. Without knowing what `dbo.uspSendEmail` is (is it a CLR SP?) this is hard impossible to debug but I would start there. If you get stuck, post the DDL and/or CLR Code.

Comment: hi @Larnu 
the dbo.uspSendEmail is a procedure i created, that has the code i posted before, it just has that. i'm sorry, i dont't get what you mean with CLR SP

Comment: What *"code i posted before"*? `uspSendEmail` is not defined in your question, and there are not edits where it was previously in the question. Without that DDL, this is impossible for us to answer.

Comment: i added in the original code what i think you asked

Comment: OK, so you *are* using `sp_send_dbmail`, it's just hidden away. `sp_send_dbmail` returns an `OUTPUT` parameter `@mailitem_id` (you'll lose this because of your usp mind). I suggest trying to send an email and capturing the value of `@mailitem_id` and then inspecting `msdb.dbo.sysmail_faileditems` and `msdb.dbo.sysmail_log`. The reason  for the failure will be in the `description` column from `sysmail_log`. If you find the error, and don't understand it, add it to your question.

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_faileditems fi
     JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmail_log l ON fi.mailitem_id = l.mailitem_id
WHERE fi.mailitem_id = {Mail item ID};`

Comment: sysmail_faileditems only returns two e-mails, from when i was setting up the database mail. i don't know if that's what was expected but in the database mail log it tells me that DatabaseMail proccess is shutting down, dated like a couple of months ago

Comment: So are all the emails simply sitting in the system, not being sent? If the Database mail process is off, then of course the email won't send.

Comment: but the sysmail_faileditems only returns two e-mails, from a year ago. another thing, dont know if it helps or not, this used to work, it worked like 4 or 5 times, and without nothing being changed it stopped working

Comment: If the Database Mail process is off, the email will never get to the failed items stage. The mail has to be attempted to be sent to it to fail.

Comment: [Database Mail XPs Server Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/database-mail-xps-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15) might assist, *if* database mail is off, but configured

Comment: As others have said, your procedure that calls .. is not looking at or capturing the return value from the call to :   
sp_send_dbmail  You need to capture this value.  without looking at the value, you're "pretending" everything works all the time.                            documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15  Return Code Values
A return code of 0 means success. Any other value means failure. The error code for the statement that failed is stored in the @@ERROR variable.

Comment: got to a new code, i added it to the initial post, but got this message:

Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.

not in the right path?